# How to show that the function $f(x)=\frac{a}{2}{\|x-b\|}_{2}^{2}+\log({c|\nabla x|}^{2}+1)$ is quasiconvex?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I need to show that the function
$f(x)=\frac{a}{2}{\|x-b\|}_{2}^{2}+\log({c|\nabla x|}^{2}+1)$ is a quasiconvex function for an optimization problem, where $a$,$b$, and $c$ are fixed and $\nabla$ is the gradient operator. I have decided to prove it by using the fact that any monotonic function is quasiconvex. For this purpose, I need to show that  there exists some $t$ such that $f$ is decreasing for $x<t$ and increasing for $x>t$. As a result, I need to show that if $x<t$ then $\nabla f(x)<0$ and
if $x>t$ then $\nabla f(x)>0$. I have obtained the formulation of $\nabla f(x)$ as
$\nabla f(x)=a(x-b)-\operatorname{div}(\frac{c}{{c|\nabla x|}^{2}+1}\nabla x)$, where $\operatorname{div}$ is the divergence operator. Since this formulation contains the divergence operator, I do not know how to continue. I really appreciate if someone could please give me some directions or a better way of proving that $f(x)$ is quasiconvex.

Comment: this is a differential equation, and you want to show that the functions that satisfies it are convex?

Comment: @LinAlg It is the objective function of an optimization problem and I need to show that it is qausiconvex.

Comment: How do you compute $\nabla x$? I know $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$ so $\nabla ||x-b||^2 = 2(x-b)$, but what is $\nabla x$?

Comment: I compute $\nabla x$ as $\nabla x =[\frac{dx}{dx1} \frac{dx}{dx2}]$ where $\frac{dx}{dx1}$ and $\frac{dx}{dx2}$ represent the derivative along the horizontal and vertical axis.

Comment: What type of object is $x$?

Comment: x is an image so we can say it is a matrix.

Comment: So then what is the meaning of $\frac{dx}{dx_1}$? You can take the derivative of a function, not a matrix. I'm guessing you mean we are applying a discrete derivative operator to $x$, but this should be made explicit.

Comment: Yes, exactly $\frac{dx}{dx1}$ is the discrete derivative along the horizontal direction.